# Ruby, getting path from path+filename

Tags: ruby, directory

Programming language: Ruby 1.9

Problem String: `C:/Test/blah.txt`
to `C:/Test/`

I know it's an easy question, but Google and the Ruby quickref for `File` have no solution for me.
And I have no experience with Regex.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Use the Ruby [`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M000027) method.

```
File.dirname("C:/Test/blah.txt")
# => "C:/Test"
```

Comment: For me, `File.dirname("/a/b/c/d")` correctly returns `/a/b/c` but `File.dirname("/a/b/c/d/")` (trailing slash) *also* returns `/a/b/c`.

Comment: There is just too much information without context in the ruby docs to find ~exactly~ what you're looking for at the moment. Great to brush up on if you already knew it or study if you're trying to know everything, horrible if you are on a project and just need to know this one thing.

Thanks so much for this answer, made life a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 1):

More versatile would be the Ruby Pathname class:

```
require 'pathname'

pn = Pathname.new("C:/Test/blah.txt")
p pn.dirname.to_s + Pathname::SEPARATOR_LIST
```

which gives `C:/Test/`.